# What is the preferred way to undo a `svn switch` with svn 1.7?

Tags: svn

Switching below the root of a project, svn switches that subdirectory only. Prior svn 1.7 one could simply delete that directory and run an update.

But now with svn 1.7, it doesn't store svn-information per directory. How can I undo the effect of the switch?

<sub>extra: apart the command line client, can it be done via TortoiseSVN? :) on win32</sub>

<sub>note this question was already asked, but for svn < 1.7 which is a *quite* different situation</sub>

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing, or simply switch back to the original location?

Comment: @JBNizet, I've tried to switch back to the original location, as well as utilize `--ignore-ancestry`. Apart from a strange lock situation that I needed to Clean, this worked. But I'm hoping for something more automatic or more trivial to automatize. By the way, what do you mean by "doing the same thing"? Deleting the directory didn't help, if you mean that. The post-switch location is not stored in the directory, but at the top of the working copy tree. Thanks for the comment, I hope it's now more clear!